# TTFB difference if using exit in php code

Tags: php, performance, typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I have a TYPO3 installation which has a very high TTFB value by each request.

It is 950 ms.

The problem is, that the TYPO3 adminPanel (a tool for debugging the content generation) says it only need 400-450 ms.

The file name is index.php this file serves the request. The content is the following:

```
require __DIR__ . '/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Core/Bootstrap.php';
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Core\Bootstrap::getInstance()
    ->baseSetup('')
    ->redirectToInstallerIfEssentialConfigurationDoesNotExist();

require(PATH_tslib . 'index_ts.php');
```

So if I change one thing and write an **exit** on the last line of the index.php:

```
require __DIR__ . '/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Core/Bootstrap.php';
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Core\Bootstrap::getInstance()
    ->baseSetup('')
    ->redirectToInstallerIfEssentialConfigurationDoesNotExist();

require(PATH_tslib . 'index_ts.php');
exit;
```

The TTFB is only 600ms.

I have XDebug installed. With debugging I see only 2 destructor running after the line `require(PATH_tslib . 'index_ts.php');` , and of course they run also in the case of **exit**.

That require line should be the last thing is happening. Actually the whole content is ready at this moment and witch echo sent back to the client.

The TYPO3 installation uses:
 - files
 - Redis Cache
 - MySQL DB
 - output buffering

*My Questions:*

1) What could be the reason of this latency? Is there something cache / buffer / php specific?

2) What kind of risk do I have if I put an exit in the last line of the index.php of the application?

Comment: I think doing something like this is not a good idea - not because it breaks something (no idea if it does), but because it prevents you from updating fast in case of security releases. You should rather use the XDEBUG profiler to find out what takes so long... E.g. In one case that I've recently fixed, there were external JS files included, which do not exist (an extension added them). TYPO3 tried to download and merge them with the other JS files on each request, which made the site really slow.

Comment: It seems it is an issue with the apache + php. I recognised that even 200 ms passed before the first line of index.php. I installed PHP-FPM instead of mod_php and both the 200 ms at the begining and the 400 at the end are gone.